# How to apply gradient on whole page in html

Tags: html, css

[image]I'm trying to apply gradient on whole HTML page using the following CSS class that I defined in the "body" tag:

```
.gradient{
    font-family: Roboto Black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    background: #234199;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#234199 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#234199 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#234199 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
    startColorstr='#234199', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0 );
}
```

But there comes a sharp edge where the sidebar exceeds the viewport area, seems like gradient starts repeat itself (as shown in the image).
Can anybody fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using a pseudo element that you stretch to the whole page with fixed position :

```css
.gradient {
  font-family: Roboto Black;
  position: relative;
}
.gradient:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index:-2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: #234199;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#234199 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#234199 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#234199 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#234199', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<body class="gradient">

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try putting the height to auto instead of 100%?

Comment: it might help putting it on JSFiddle so i could play around with it lol

Answer (score 0):

Set `height: 100%` on the `<html>` element and it should fill the viewport.

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMjYrq

Comment: I mean that you should actually style the `<html>` element: `html { height: 100%; }`

Comment: Sorry, previous comment mistakenly posted, I actually defined height 100% for both html & body tag, but still not working.

Comment: try 100% vh viewport height, I tried this with a div worked for me